# File exist or not checking is not working in ios?

Tags: ios, file, storyboard, plist, nsfilemanager

HI i am using following code to check whether the file exist or not in my document directory but its look like its not working.When i run app in wifi then its download the plist files and save in document directory and when i force close that app and make wifi off then run again ,then its not detecting file already existing in document directory..

This is my code

```
    NSString *filename=@"Form.plist";
    NSString *filecomponent=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",filename];

    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filecomponent];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if(!fileExists){
       if([Connectivity hasConnectivity])
       {
           //Download file again
        //   NSLog(@"%@",[[config objectForKey:@"URL"]valueForKey:@"Form"]);

           [self downloadFile:[[config objectForKey:@"URL"]valueForKey:@"Form"] :filename :identifier :rb];

       }else{
           alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please check your internet connectivity." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
           [alert show];

       }

    }else{


    rb = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Form"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rb animated:YES];
    }
```

without internet now its showing only alert instead of going inside to view controller.

Comment: Move "Form.plist" file to your app bundle. Then try with '[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Form" ofType:@"plist"];' ,assign this to your filePath string.

Comment: @Karthik sivam we cannot write files into NSBundle..its restricted by Apple itself

Comment: your filePath is correct? try to print it out.

Comment: @user2990885 Of course you cannot write, but you can move it or add it manually to your app bundle.

Comment: chancy:thanks ...the path was null...thats the issue